# how to reduce the height of panel in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I make a panel in jQm .I want to reduce the height of panel .I added height property with important but it not work .I also google it did not find any solution
can you please tell me how to reduce the height of panel .?

here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/8/

```
#mypanel{

    height:100px !important
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to achieve it for reveal and push panels, because panels wraps header/footer/content in a div `ui-panel-wrapper` and push them away. So the visible height of panel equals viewport's height. It might work with overlay only.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/10/

Comment: @Aravin wait I will check ..And tell you

Comment: @Omarn how can use overlay ?

Comment: @Aravin it is not working ..pls see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/11/ .when you open the panel and open all node.it should scroll after 100px horizontally and vertically. but it is not working

Comment: what you want exactly..

Comment: @Aravin I want to scroll contend horizontally and vertically (at some height on panel example 100 px).when I  open all node if node id more it scroll vertical as well as horizontal

Comment: @Aravin it it possible ?

Comment: check and tell http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/13/

Comment: yes @Aravin perfect answer..!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JQM panel the min-height is 100%. So Try like the following in your style sheet.

```
.ui-panel{
   min-height:100px !important;
   max-height: 100px !important;
   min-width:100px !important;
   max-width: 100px !important;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Look at this <kbd>[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/13/)</kbd>

Check this for only reduce the height [**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/10/)

Comment: please remove your answer