# How to modify the height of panel in JQM

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to make the panel of Jquery mobile smaller in height . Like custom height but not able to do that although I am able to change the width of the panel easily

I know that to modify the panel we should change following **CSS**

```
.ui-panel {
    border-width: 0;
    display: block;
    max-height: none;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:70% !important;
}
```

but when I try to change the height it does not change.

Any idea would be appreciated

**UPDATE**

The current Panel looks like this

[image]

What I want is something like this but the height should be less . Because there is white space at the end of the panel that is coming over the footer that I don't want

[image]

Thanks & Regards

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187455/how-to-reduce-the-height-of-panel-in-jquery-mobile/24188861#24188861

Comment: exactly what you want..checked this one http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/13/

Comment: Wait let me update the question with some images it will make it more clear

Comment: @Aravin updated my question have a look

Comment: set `.ui-panel{
    min-height:200px !important;
    max-height: 200px !important;}` 200px is your desired panel height or make some fiddle and show ..

Comment: @Aravin  thanx bro I am playing around with it seems like I am getting there